# [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310028D, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of: 'DC=xxxxxx,DC=int'

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap

I am getting the above error and my property file contains below configurations.

```
spring.ldap.urls=ldap://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:389
spring.ldap.base=DC=xxxxxx,DC=int
spring.ldap.username=adminx@xxxxxx.int
spring.ldap.password=password
spring.ldap.authentication=simple
spring.ldap.baseEnvironment.referral=follow
```

I am getting this error when passing the data to the AD server through the postman. Here is the JSON body.
{
"username": "testad",
"password": "password",
"email": "testad@test.com"
}

Here is my service class,

```
    public void addUser(User user) {
    DirContextAdapter context = new DirContextAdapter();
    context.setAttributeValues("objectclass", new String[] {"top", "person", "organizationalPerson", "user"});
    context.setAttributeValue("sAMAccountName", user.getUsername());
    context.setAttributeValue("userPrincipalName", user.getUsername() + "@xxxx.int");
    context.setAttributeValue("mail", user.getEmail());
    context.setAttributeValue("unicodePwd", "\"" + user.getPassword() + "\"");
    context.setAttributeValue("userAccountControl", Integer.toString(512)); // Normal user


    ldapTemplate.bind("cn=" + user.getUsername() + ",ou=users,dc=xxxx,dc=int", context, null);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a minimal, runnable example which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Do you actually have an `OU=Users` in your directory?

Comment: yes. This is the distinguishedName
CN=Users,DC=xxxxx,DC=int